# SBT: obtain all passed arguments

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I'd like to get hold of all the parameters that are passed to `sbt` invocation, including JVM parameters, without knowing which exactly were provided. Is that possible?

Something like this:

```
sbt -Dsbt.ivy.home=/tmp/.ivy2 -Divy.home=/tmp/.ivy2 -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

So I'd like to see the which parameters were passed, in this case they are system properties `sbt.ivy.home` and `ivy.home`, and JVM property `XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`. I also need the corresponding values, obviously.

It would be enough if I could just get this all as a single string, maybe it's more realistic?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated example class that can print out all environment variables and the additional JVM arguments:

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean;
import java.util.*;

```
public class VMArgs{
    public static void main(String... args){
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.list(System.out);

        RuntimeMXBean runtimeMxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
        List<String> arguments = runtimeMxBean.getInputArguments();
        System.out.println ("------------------arguments-----------------------------");
        System.out.println(arguments);
    }
}
```

In your comment, you mention: `-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`. I think that is a typo, the -J is invalid. The argument should be `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled`.

If I run the above program with the `-Xmx256m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` JVM arg, the output is (Ignoring the System properties):

```
------------------arguments-------------------
[-Xmx256m, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled]
```

Which demonstrates that it does capture and output the JVM args as expected.

Comment: Nope, the `-J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` thingy is not listed there.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an additional code snippet for extracting jvm options

Comment: @Haspemulator Check the answer and your input arguments. It's working for me.